# ImageLoader NullPointerException

Tags: android, gradle, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap, imageloader

I am reciving a nullpointerexpression when I try to get a Bitmap.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
Bitmap bmp = null;
bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync("http://i.imgur.com/tx41HBE.jpg");
```

The bmp variable is null after calling the `imageLoader.loadImageSync()` method , what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
  private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
    .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 Mb
    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
    .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
    .build();
imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
Bitmap bmp = null;
                    bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync("http://i.imgur.com/tx41HBE.jpg");
```

The reason might be that you didn't initialize the **imageLoader** using `imageLoader.init(config)`